# Moving Folder in a Directory

Tags: vb.net

I have a path D:\myfolder1\mysubfolder
I want to move the mysubfolder to the root(D:)
Here is the code I am trying to use which gives me an error saying invalid parameter.

```
Public Sub Movefolder()
    Dim listFolders() As String = Directory.GetDirectories("D:\myfolder1")
    Dim curf As String

    For Each curf In listFolders 'listfolders(1) would be the mysubfolder
        Dim DirInfo As New System.IO.DirectoryInfo(curf)
        Directory.Move(curf, "D:\") 'This is where I get the error
    Next

End Sub
```

Can anybody point out where I am doing wrong or is there a more easier or atleast another way to it??

Comment: What you're doing wrong is not having read the docs for [`Directory.Move()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.move.aspx), notably the first sentence under **Remarks**. The destination must be the name of the new directory that will be created by the move, not its intended parent directory. I.e. using an existing directory as a destination (i.e. `D:\` won't work), you need to join it with the base name of the source directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.move.aspx), the destination path must *include* the new name of the file or directory you are moving.

As you already retrieve the `DirectoryInfo` for the folder being moved, you can use its [`Name` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.name.aspx) to get the name of the directory you are moving, which you can then append to the destination path:

```
For Each curf In listFolders '// listfolders(1) would be the mysubfolder
    Dim DirInfo As New System.IO.DirectoryInfo(curf)
    Directory.Move(curf, Path.Combine("D:\", DirInfo.Name))
Next
```

Comment: Thank you very much it worked. But it does not make any logical sense to me. If you could explain me. the dirinfo.name holds the string D:\myfolder1\mysubfolder and combining it again with "D:\" how does that go on please??

Comment: @user2625656: No, not quite. The `DirectoryInfo` instance can be imagined like an object that represents the directory, no matter what its name is. Now, various properties of the object provide you with information about the directory - for example, [`FullName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.fullname.aspx) will return the full path to the directory ("D:\myfolder1\mysubfolder"), and [`Name`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.name.aspx) will return just the name of the directory itself ("mysubfolder").